# Do these lines intersect?

Tags: linear-algebra

So I'm trying to figure out if two lines, namely:

$[4,3,-2] + s \cdot [3,-5,6]$ and $ [1,4,8] + t \cdot [-1,3,-2]$ interesect.

Note that $s$ and $t$ are some variables.

So I do some algebraic fiddling with this to get:

$$3s - 1t = -3$$ $$ -5s - 3t = 1 $$ $$ 6s -2t = 6$$

and I solve by Gauss Jordan but I end up with the matrix:

$$ \begin{matrix} 1&0&-2 \\ 0 & 1 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & -6 \end{matrix}$$

Does this mean that they intersect or not...? Because this seems to imply that there is no solution because of the last line, right?

Comment: The first equation does not look right.  I get $3s+t=-3$.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Agreed. Also $s$ and $t$ are most certainly _not_ constants.

Comment: Sorry, I meant variables. What is wrong with the equation?

Comment: The first equation should be $4+3s=1-1t$, which can be rewritten as $3s+t=-3$.

Comment: The third equation also has the wrong sign for $t$.

Answer (score 1):

If you correct the equations as suggested in the comments:$$3s + 1t = -3$$ $$ -5s - 3t = 1 $$ $$ 6s +2t = 6$$  You can note that the first and third are contradictory, so the lines do not intersect.

Comment: Can you tell me what you mean by "first and third are contradictory"? Also, if I happen to get a solution in the future like the one I got, what does it mean for the intersection of lines?